# creating a three permutation list with two value

Tags: python

is there a way to automatically generate a list of permutations with three value when you only give it two ?

```
 E = {'M', 'F'}
permute_k = list(itertools.permutations(E, 3))
```

like the code above will give me a empty list like this []

but I want a list that contain the two value as three element like this [’MMM’, ’MMF’, ’MFM’, ...]

any suggestion

Answer (score 6):

In this case you want a cartesian product, with a `repeat` arg

```
>>> list(itertools.product(E, repeat=3))
[('F', 'F', 'F'), ('F', 'F', 'M'), ('F', 'M', 'F'), ('F', 'M', 'M'), ('M', 'F', 'F'), ('M', 'F', 'M'), ('M', 'M', 'F'), ('M', 'M', 'M')]
```

and if you want the elements as strings instead of tuples you can `str.join`

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(E, repeat=3)]
['FFF', 'FFM', 'FMF', 'FMM', 'MFF', 'MFM', 'MMF', 'MMM']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `itertools.permutations` returns the subsequences of the input iterable. If you specify `r` > len(iterable) you will have an empty list. Your iterable should be 'MMMFFF' here. By the way a set is not an iterable so you have to manipulate list or a string instead.

```py
E = 'MMMFFF'  # or ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F']
permute_k = list(itertools.permutations(E, 3))
permute_k = [''.join(perm) for perm in permute_k]  # to have a list of strings
```